# Question about the lim inf of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to prove that $\inf_{x\geq0}f(x)=0$ implies that $\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)=0$ if $f:\mathbb R_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb R_{>0}$ is a continuous function which does not vanish?

Any suggestion of book with this kind of proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\inf_{x \ge 0} f(x) = 0$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_n \ge 0$ such that $f(x_n) \le 1/n$. Now, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ must diverge at $+\infty$. In fact, were this not the case, by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem we could find a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x^*, k\to\infty$. Since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N} , x_n \ge0$, also $x^*\ge0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x^*), k\to \infty$. But $0\le f(x_{n_k})\le\frac{1}{n_k} \to0, k\to\infty$, implying that $0<f(x^*)=0$, a contradiction. It follows that $x_n \to \infty, n\to\infty$, from which
\begin{equation}
0\le\mathrm{liminf}_{x \to \infty}f(x) \le \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=0,
\end{equation}
i.e., $\mathrm{liminf}_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$.